# rate metrics generation via OpenTelemetry

Tags: open-telemetry-collector, otel

In Prometheus, we have an option to calculate rate of the metrics example rate(http_requests_total[2m]).

OTEL having the metric generation processor i.e. experimental_metricsgeneration and is it possible to calculate the rate of an existing metric or is there any other way it can be achieved?